# Is there a way to test if an Iterable contains a pattern using python's "match" statement?

Tags: python, iterable, iterable-unpacking, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

This has to do with the new Python 3.10 beta and the new `match` syntax.
Is there any way to check if a pattern is simply contained in an iterable? the most obvious solution, to simply put two wildcards on either side, but that raises a `SyntaxError` due to the unpacking syntax coming from iterable unpacking.

Is there any possible way to do this?
NOTE: the use of things like wrapper classes around `numbers`
in the example would be fine, as long as it works using the match blocks and is at least somewhat readable, but I have already tried this somewhat and not had much success

example:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9] #does not have to be a list, could be a class if needed

match numbers:
    # this just raises a SyntaxError, but I need a way to do something equivalent to this
    case [*_, (5 | 6), *_]:
        print("match!")
```

Comment: what about using any() ?

Comment: any() isn't able to be used in a match statement, nor is any function; the exact error you get is `TypeError: called match pattern must be a type`

Comment: with old version of python : `print any([not not re.match(pattern, str(n)) for n in numbers])`

Comment: What's wrong with `if 5 in numbers or 6 in numbers:`?

Answer (score 6):

No, we don't currently have any plans to support iterable containment checks as part of the structural pattern matching syntax.

The best way to rewrite your example in legal Python is with a normal `if` test:

```py
if any(i in (5, 6) for i in numbers):
    print("match!")
```

If the containment check is just one part of a more complex pattern, you can write it as a guard instead:

```py
match something:
    case [pattern, capturing, numbers] if any(i in (5, 6) for i in numbers):
        print("match!")
```

Of course, if you have a *sequence*, it is also possible to find an item at a *known* index:

```py
match numbers:
    case [_, _, _, 5 | 6, *_]:
        print("match at position 3!")
    case [*_, 5 | 6, _, _, _]:
        print("match at position -4!")
```

---

With that said...

> the use of things like wrapper classes around `numbers` in the example would be fine, as long as it works using the match blocks and is at least somewhat readable

...I suppose mapping patterns could be hacked to make this work (provided that all of your items are hashable and don't have unusual equality rules):

```py
match dict.fromkeys(numbers):
    case {5: _} | {6: _}:
        print("match!")
```

I strongly recommend the `if` form over this, though.

Comment: In the last case, what is special about dict matching?  Why does (appropriately indented) `match {5: None}:  case {5: None}:` work whereas `match {5}: case {5}` raise a syntax error?